# Sfill caused a disk max capacity error to show

Tags: secure-erase

The ooooooo.ooo  created by sfill is now larger than my root directory.  Can i let it run or do i need to cancel it and make a larger root partition?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: And what do you mean by "larger". How can a file be larger than a directory?

Comment: I started the sfill command thats part of secure delete.   the entered command was        sudo sfill -lv /partition          This created a file on my root directory called     "oooooooooooo.ooo"  and it grew in size that is larger than the root directory has room available for.    I'm assuming that this is the method by which sfill or secure delete wipes a drive before zeroing it.  The thing is i am not sure so i would like to know if this is acceptable or will it not work?

Comment: By "root", you mean /partition?

Comment: yes that is what i meant by root partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `sfill` is to **fill your available disk space** with patterns that will overwrite any residual data from older files and directories that have been deleted since.

Therefore, you must not be concerned by the size of 'ooooooo.ooo', it will be as large as possible. No need to stop `sfill` then. You must not enlarge your partition either, as the file will then get larger too.

As for the file being larger than the partition's available space, even if this is technically possible ([sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)), this is probably false in that context. You are probably comparing the file size with the available space as you see it as a regular user, but Linux `ext` partitions are generally created with 5% more space (this extra-space is only usable by root; you can see it with `dumpe2fs -h /dev/your_ext_partition | grep ^Reserved`).